# Laravel Route::get('foo'); vs Route::get('/foo');

Tags: php, laravel

I wonder if there is any difference between

```
Route::get('foo');
```

and

```
Route::get('/foo');
```

I can access both pages through my website and api by **www.mysite.com/foo** but is there any difference or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls

Comment: If you run `php artisan route:list` you'll see that they get registered under the same route whichever syntax you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to start a URL with a `/` so that the intended URL is returned instead of its parent or child.

Let's say if your browsing on a website to `/example_1/` then you have a link on the page that has `example_1.html`. Without the forward flash its going to attempt to visit the page according to the following URL: `/example_1/example_1.html`. While with the forward flash it'll assume you mean the top level which will be in this case the following URL: `example.com/example_1.html.` So with `index` files it wouldn't be a problem since they'll be loaded automaticly anyway. But it could cause problems with loading files or functions in deep `URL`'s and not defining the full `URL`.

Normally it's best to always use `/`. in my experience i always use them as it is more friendly when you change the structure of your site, through there is no right or wrong assuming that the intended page always gets returned. Do keep in mind that on bigger projects it's better to always specify your full link with the intended `/`'s because then you'll have a full, organized structure of your project and website.

I don't really know if there are also SEO rules about these kind of topics but maybe there are some so you should check that out aswell just to be sure.

Does it make a big difference? No, is it necessary? No, but it is the best way to always fully define your `URL`.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no difference in those two options.

If you follow up the `get` function and go on to see what's happening with the passed `$uri` parameter, you can see that it is handled by method `Illuminate\Routing\Router::prefix($uri)` which trims the slash from the uri.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference when defining a Laravel route like this that I have seen.

Answer (score 0):

In laravel there will be no difference while defining routes, But in general without using `/` that means its a relative path.